# g++ Parse error at ":"

Tags: c++, qt, g++, signals-slots

`g++` is reporting a parse error with the code below:

```
class Sy_timeLineDelegateScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Sy_timeLineDelegateScene( Sy_animPropertyTimeLine* timeline,
                              Sy_animClock* clock,
                              QObject* parent = nullptr );
    virtual ~Sy_timeLineDelegateScene() {}

protected slots:   // Parse error at ":"
    typedef QMap< Sy::Frame, Sy_timeLineDelegateKey* > DelegateTimeLine;
...
```

My class is derived from `QObject` and I have declared the `Q_OBJECT` macro before the error, but if I comment out the `slots` part, it compiles fine.  I have used `Qt` for years and never seen this before, it must be something stupid, but I can't see what's causing the problem.

Comment: Isn't it just `protected:` without the `slots`?

Comment: Did you pass the code through moc before g++?

Comment: "slots" and "signals" sections should only contain functions; neither types nor member variables.

Comment: @juergend, that's a QT thing. The 'MOC' (meta-object compiler) is a kind of preprocessor that wrangles that stuff.

Comment: @Roddy I've got an `#include <QGraphicsScene>` that pulls that in.

Comment: @leemes That's it!  Thank you, I must have missed that in the documentation...  Stick that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm such a bonehead. I went to change my public to public Q_SLOTS and forgot to refactor my constructor and destructor to a new public section >_<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "slots" and "signals" sections in a class definition should only contain functions; neither types nor member variables.

You should move the `typedef` in a public, protected or private section:

```
class Sy_timeLineDelegateScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Sy_timeLineDelegateScene( Sy_animPropertyTimeLine* timeline,
                              Sy_animClock* clock,
                              QObject* parent = nullptr );
    virtual ~Sy_timeLineDelegateScene() {}

    typedef QMap< Sy::Frame, Sy_timeLineDelegateKey* > DelegateTimeLine;

protected slots:
...
```